# Equivalence of definitions of ergodic action

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, group-actions, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a probability measure space $(X, \mu)$ by measure-preserving transformations. I have read the two following definitions of ergodicity of such an action:

1. For every measurable set $A$ such that $\mu(gA \Delta A) = 0$ for all $g \in G$, we have $\mu(A) = 0$ or $1$.
2. For every measurable set $A$ such that $gA = A$ for all $g \in G$, we have $\mu(A) = 0$ or $1$.

It is clear that 1 implies 2. It is not hard to show that 2 implies 1 if the group is countable. But what about the more general case? What if, for instance, $G$ is a separable group acting continuously on a topological, or even metric space $X$? Would that be enough?

Also, it is clear that a transitive action satisfies 2. But when does it satisfy 1 in the general case? Would the hypotheses above help?

Comment: You might want to check the conventions being used in condition 2. In Durrett's probability textbook, for example, in the chapters on ergodic theory, he writes "$A=B$" as shorthand for "$A=B$ $\mu$ almost everywhere", in which case 2  clearly implies 1.

Comment: Proposition 8.3 of 'Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory' by Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward states that your statements 1 and 2 are equivalent if $G$ is a $\sigma$-compact metric group acting continuously on a $\sigma$-compact metric space.